# Will one 3/4" fitting cause any flow or pressure issues in a 1" line?

Tags: pipe, well, filter

Well water with a pressure tank, the outlet is 1 1/4 but has a short reducing piece that is 3/4".
The 3/4 line is about 2 inches long and then goes into a 1" line to the water filter system. The filter system lines are about 5 ft total length, all 1".
Line is then reduced back to 3/4 to supply the house.
Am I going to have pressure, flow or supply issues? Current homeowner says they have no issues, but it's one person and we are a family of 5.

Comment: would you ask the question if the 2" piece of 3/4" pipe was at the end of the 3/4" house supply pipe?

Answer (score 1):

Any, effect - yes. Enough to be a problem - unknown until you try it.

Given that the house supply is 3/4, **probably** no problem to speak of.

I recently swapped a section of my incoming line (to the pressure tank Tee) from 1" to 3/4" because it was overdrawing the pump when the well is full (there are fancier pressure-adaptive flow control fittings, but I haven't bothered with one yet.) The actual tank-Tee piping is still 1".

Before you go nuts trying to optimize flow, get the data on your well and pump to be sure they can actually support more flow - and prepare for considerably more repiping than one 3/4" adapter.

Biggest difference easily made in that direction is to split the feed to the water heater at the point where the line goes from 1" to 3/4" so you have 3/4 to cold uses and 3/4 to hot uses, independently. 3/4" direct to the water heater from that point.

Answer (score 0):

Before you over think your situation, do as @ECNERWAL said; "Before you go nuts trying to optimize flow, get the data on your well and pump to be sure they can actually support more flow - and prepare for considerably more repiping than one 3/4" adapter.

Biggest difference easily made in that direction is to split the feed to the water heater at the point where the line goes from 1" to 3/4" so you have 3/4 to cold uses and 3/4 to hot uses, independently. 3/4" direct to the water heater from that point".

Then, try living in the house first and if you think the water supply is not enough to satisfy everyone in the house, make the  improvements you feel will correct the deficiencies.  You could buy a bigger well pump if the well will support it. You could increase the size of the storage tank and the piping in the whole house. I have lived with a well and it is usually not quite as good as a constant 75-80 PSI city water supply.

Comment: There's not a lot here that isn't just a reworded repetition of Ecnerwal's answer (as you've admitted). I'd suggest adding some info or deleting this.